Scene Transition Takes Long Time
I have a shop scene. There is a button that brings player back to menu scene. But transition from shop to menu a takes a bit long and I do not know why. I checked all codes and debugged them. Also turned all codes into comment and only one line of code remained which is SceneManager.LoadScene(0); , it is still same. I do not think it is about the codes. Something about Unity maybe but I am not sure. Does anybody have any idea why could it happen ?
Video example:

Google Drive

YouTube


Only codes that are working in this video are below:
I have also removed fade panel and tried. It was same.
 pubic void FadePanel()
 {
     if (fadeIn)
     {
         if (fadePanel.alpha < 1)
         {
             fadePanel.alpha += fadeTime * Time.deltaTime;
             if (fadePanel.alpha >= 1)
             {
                 fadeIn = false;
                 SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
             }
         }
     }

     if (fadeOut)
     {
         if (fadePanel.alpha > 0)
         {
             fadePanel.alpha -= fadeTime * Time.deltaTime;
             if (fadePanel.alpha <= 0)
             {
                 fadeOut = false;

             }
         }
     }
 }

I checked profiler and saw this warning. I do not know what I should do about that.

Application.WaitForAsyncOperationToComplete
3829.10ms
Scene Loading take more than expected and it is not about the codes I think.

The video asks for google login. Please post it somewhere on a public host to reduce any security risks on your account.

I can not edit now but here is Youtube Link : https://youtu.be/EDgIOppub4U

What is the number of objects on the Menu scene, compared to the Shop scene? Also, how many GOs do you have set as DontDestroyOnLoad()? Do the objects that are persistent increase when you swap between scenes (for example as duplicates)?

There are not much. 14 objects in menu and even around 30 in shop including Childobjects. But I turned all off and tried and still same. Only object in DontDestroyOnLoad() is update debugger.

Do you have any forced delays in the code when swapping scenes? For example waiting in a loop, such as a while(condition) {}  or any CoRoutines?
